# print_r() for many objects

Tags: php

For logging purposes, I am looking for something that behaves like `print_r()` (or similar), but accepts not only one object to be displayed, but many of them. Such as `var_dump()` is doing.

Desired:

```
$text = "Error " . print_r($obj1, $obj2, $obj3...);  // print_r many objects in one call
log_message('info', $text);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Put them into an array?!

Comment: [print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)'s second parameter set to true will return the text. Maybe you missed that? Otherwise, yes, just surround that with `[]`.

Comment: What's the point of this construction? I mean, you could say `print_r($obj1); print_r($obj2);` and it would print what you want.

Comment: Asking what's the point of 'why that?' is just asking why var_dump() is accepting many objects to print. My point is for automating it in a more complex, higher level process. But many other uses come to my mind.

Comment: @Peter Krebs , yes, I am aware of the second parameter of print_r(). ;) But your suggestion is exactly what I was looking for: Just surround the many objects with [] for converting it to a single array. Simple; brilliant. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PeterKrebs Something like this? `$text = print_r([$obj1, $obj2, $obj3], true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one is doing it... Self-answered question, based on @Peter Krebs comment:

Nesting the many objects within [ ] for converting it to a single array can just do the job:

```
$text = "Error " . print_r([$obj1, $obj2, $obj3]);  // print_r many objects in one call
log_message('info', $text);
```

Simple, smart.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom wrapper function that uses '[Variable-length argument list (`...$args`)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)' to catch an unknown number of arguments, then loop over those to show them using `print_r`:

```php
<?php

function logError(...$objs) {
    foreach ($objs as $obj) {
        print_r($obj);
    }
}

logError(1, 2, 3);
```